# VB Serialisation to C# Serialisation

Tags: c#, vb.net, serialization

I started programming in a Company where a program was written in VB.
I converted it to C# because it's a much cleaner code.

In VB they did something like that:

```
    Class Program
        Friend Shared Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim obj As New Class1()
        Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream("test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        Dim bf As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
            bf.Serialize(fs, obj)
            fs.Close()

            fs = New System.IO.FileStream("test.txt", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
            bf = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
            obj = bf.Deserialize(fs)
            For Each item As String In obj.myList
                Console.WriteLine(item)
            Next
            Console.Read()
        End Sub
    End Class

    <Serializable> _
    Class Class1
        Public myList As List(Of String)
        Public Sub New()
            myList = New List(Of String)()
            myList.Add(True)
            myList.Add(False)
            myList.Add(True)
            myList.Add(False)
            myList.Add(True)
            myList.Add(False)
            myList.Add(True)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

But in C# the assignment of a bool to a String-Var is of course forbidden.
I wrote a class in C# that is named Class1Old which includes all members as declared in VB,
but when I deserialize in C# I catch the exception "String can not be converted in Boolean".

I watched in the written *.txt file and the result was very confusing:

```
        ÿÿÿÿ          JConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
    PublicKeyToken=null   
    ConsoleApplication1.Class1   
    myListSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
    _items_size_version                       True   False
```

I can't imagine how theese 7 values are converted and reconverted.

**How can I deserialize the file in C# which was written from VB?**

hope somebody can help me...

EDIT:

Now I include a VB dll-project to my ptoject including the "old" code.
my C#-code calls a method in the VB-code which starts deserializing.
But I still receive the ArgumentException:

```
The object of type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" can not be converted to type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Boolean]".
```

But all arguments in the serialized class are the same type in my actual project as in my pure VB project.

So what das cause that exception??

greets
Henrik

Answer (score 3):

The assignment of a bool to a string variable is also forbidden in VB.net - unless your predecessor did not use Option Strict On. In that case your C# rant is meaninglas - the coding practice was at fault, not VB.Net.

There is no easy way to deserialize the class - I think the best way would be Bool Properties which, when set, are also creating the string variables.
This would work with xml serialiazation, I am not sure that if it works with the Binary formatter.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on "fixing" something that isn't broken, I suppose you will need to deserialize into an intermediate "translation" class that has the list defined as Object or Boolean. This class will then output a Class1 object.